# Force range in R Kaplan-Meier time component

Tags: r, probability

I have a numeric `time` variable and I want to observe my data using `R`'s Kaplan-Meier implementation. The common way is:

```
 km <- survfit(Surv(time,event)~1)
 summary(km)
```

But I have specific range of time that I want processed say 1-3,4-6, and so on but my method returns an error.

```
 km <- survfit(Surv(time=c(c(1,3),c(4,6),c(7,9)),event)~1)
 summary(km)
```

Is this possible with another code or do I have to change the `time` variable to suit my needs (ie recode into categories)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `time` variable you provide should include the survival times of the individual observations in your dataset.

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want the KM-estimates for specific timepoints you can get those by using the times argument in the `summary` function for `survfit`:

```
summary(km, times=c(1,3,4,6,7,9))
```

Of course you could also plot the KM-curve using `plot(km)` to visualize it.

Comment: Thank you. Specifically I want a combined KM computation for a range of time say 1 - 3. Is that possible?

Comment: That is not common in survival analysis to my knowlegde. You could perhaps take the median observed survival probability for a specific range of timepoints, but I am not sure whether that is statistically sound, so I would advice to report the KM-estimates at a specific timepoint rather than for a range of times.

Comment: Note taken. Thank you very much @Rob.